# RxSwift unwrap optional handy function?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Currently I have created a function `unwrapOptional` to safely unwrap the optional input in the stream.

```
    func unwrapOptional<T>(x: Optional<T>) -> Observable<T> {
       return x.map(Observable.just) ?? Observable.empty()
    }

    let aOpt: String? = "aOpt"
    _ = Observable.of(aOpt).flatMap(unwrapOptional).subscribeNext { x in print(x)}

    let aNil: String? = nil
    _ = Observable.of(aNil).flatMap(unwrapOptional).subscribeNext { x in print(x)}

    let a: String = "a"
    _ = Observable.of(a).flatMap(unwrapOptional).subscribeNext { x in print(x)}

   // output 
    aOpt
    a
```

What I want to archive is to create a handy function instead of using `flatMap(unwrapOptional)`, for example

```
Observable.of(a).unwrapOptional()
```

Something I tried to do, but it never compiles...

```
extension ObservableType {
    func unwrapOptional<O : ObservableConvertibleType>() -> RxSwift.Observable<O.E> {
        return self.flatMap(unwrapOptional)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want the `unwrapOptional` method to only work on observables that have optional type.

So you somehow have to constraint the `Element` of `Observable` to conform to the `Optional` protocol.

```
extension Observable where Element: OptionalType {
    /// Returns an Observable where the nil values from the original Observable are
    /// skipped
    func unwrappedOptional() -> Observable<Element.Wrapped> {
        return self.filter { $0.asOptional != nil }.map { $0.asOptional! }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, Swift does not define such a protocol (`OptionalType`). So you also need to define it yourself

```
/// Represent an optional value
///
/// This is needed to restrict our Observable extension to Observable that generate
/// .Next events with Optional payload
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var asOptional:  Wrapped? { get }
}

/// Implementation of the OptionalType protocol by the Optional type
extension Optional: OptionalType {
    var asOptional: Wrapped? { return self }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

checkout `unwrap` at https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwift-Ext :)

or https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxOptional

For now, you should use `RxOptional` for your personal needs
However, `RxSwift-Ext` will be growth exponentially in next 2-3 months :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version without needing `OptionalType` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36788483/13000)

```
extension Observable {

    /// Returns an `Observable` where the nil values from the original `Observable` are skipped
    func unwrap<T>() -> Observable<T> where Element == T? {
        self
            .filter { $0 != nil }
            .map { $0! }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

RxSwift now supports [compactMap()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observables/CompactMap.swift). So, now you can do things like:

```swift
func unwrap(_ a: Observable<Int?>) -> Observable<Int> {
  return a.compactMap { $0 }
}
```